# Can not take request in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have `controller`  class like this

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PrsService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginTry",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginAction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

and configuration classes

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
       public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
          InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
          resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
          resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
          return resolver;
       }

       @Override
       public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
       }

}

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
          return return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
          return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
          return new String[] { "/" };
       }

}
```

and my `login.jsp`  file

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have any `web.xml` content  and `sprint-servlet.xml` I just want to write everything in java and with annotations.

When i am sending request `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp/login` it is returning `login.jsp` but when I am trying to send  request with `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp/loginTry`   and `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp/loginAction` I am getting `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`  error  and java is telling me `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMvcApp/loginTry] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'` Did I missed some configuration or what is wrong in my code ? When I saw google examples they are doing just like my but their code is working fine :X P.S I am beginner in SPRING

Comment: Can you try removing `@RequestMapping("/")` from `PrsService` ? And I think, you don't need `@ComponentScan` here - `PrsService` is not a configuration.

Comment: I tried to remove `@RequestMapping("/")` but still did not work. `@ComponentScan` here is scanning every configuration under this package .

Comment: Just add a default Constructor in `PrsService` and add a `Syso`, to verify whether its instance is getting created or not. If not getting created add `@ComponentScan("top level package")` on your `WebMvcConfig` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this things.

1. Wish to know, where have you defined your @springbootapplication. Or @componentscan with right package defined in the value filed. Hope, its been setup in Spring Application Java class.
2. As stated above, you have used an extra "/" in the @RequestMapping("/"). Either you remove it or add some sting after, say "/api", and call appropriately
3. Remove @componentscan in PrsService. Feels redundant.

Comment: Thank you man , I tried this things you wrote and it works  fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have added an extra '/', as you are using RequestMapping at  both class and method level,for now add an extra '/' in your url(see below) and try,Hope it Helps.

http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp//loginTry

Comment: No it does not working. I tried `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp//loginTry` but I have same error I remove @RequestMapping("/") from my PrsService  and try `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp/loginTry` but i have  same error

Answer (score 0):

@Controller

```
@ComponentScan
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PrsService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginTry",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

That means your url is http://localhost:8080//loginTryenter code here